# Regex match 2 string (only letter and number part) ignore the hyphen

Tags: java, regex, mongodb, morphia

Here is the question. Wondering if the mongo query function can match **11123** to **11-1-2-3**

I tried regex in the morphia. Can't figure it out.

Anyone can help?

**Update question**

Ok people asked me why I need this. Here is the background.

In dataBase the id is store as asdsad-sdas12-13sada12-sadsad
But somehow the data we get that use for tracking and querying become asdsadsdas1213sada12sadsad, all the hyphens are missing.

I know we can apply regex in the mongo query (morphia). But wondering if it is possible to have this kind of regex.

Comment: Why did you tag with Java, and what is a `Morphia`?

Comment: "Can" and **"should"** are really different concepts. *"Should I use unbounded regex matching?"*. No you should not. Is there some reason why you could not format your input "number" by the expected "string" format you have used? Is there some reason why the "string" could not be simply stored as the "number" if that is the query of significance here?  Could do with some more explanation of what you really need to do, since you are likely not considering the most logical and "performant" alternatives.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen https://mongodb.github.io/morphia/

Comment: @NeilLunn I asked question for a reason. So the format in the db is uuid with hyphen. But the input string the hyphen is missing. So we don't know where is the hyphen. So want to use the non-hyphen string to query the normal uuid (with hyphen) Let me know if it make sense.

Comment: I do understand "why" you asked it that way and my response was such because particularly if it's a "UUID" or any "known" format, then it makes more sense to simply "format the input" to that which is expected in storage, or "vice versa" by storing "without" the hyphens. The reason I say this is whilst you "can" backtrack for patterns separated by hyphens, it's just "not a good idea" for performance reasons. An "exact match" or even "an exact beginning of string" is always going to perform better. Therefore you "should" do that instead. So the comment was for you to "adjust your thinking".